# Black/White Image with unsigned char is blue instead of black C++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, binary, char

I'm reading an .img Gray Scale Image (512 byte header, 512 x 512 pixels x 8 bits per pixel).

There I'm determining a threshold to turn the Gray-Scale image into a binary image (black/white).

But when I assign 0 to the pixels, it turns out to be a light blue (#01fffd)?!?! When I use the value 2 it's almost black (#020100).

Can you explain me how this comes?

I read the image like this:

```
int width = 512;
int height = 512;
File* imageFilePointerIn = fopen("image.img", "r+b");
File* binaryImageFilePointerOut = fopen("imageOut.img",
            "w+b");
unsigned char* header = new unsigned char[512];
unsigned char** imageData = new unsigned char*[width];
unsigned char** binaryImageArray = new unsigned char*[width];
fread(header, sizeof(char), 512, imageFilePointerIn);
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    data[i] = new unsigned char[height];
    fread(data[i], sizeof(char), height, imageFilePointerIn);
}
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    binaryImageArray[i] = new unsigned char[height];
}
char unsigned thresholdBinaryImage = 128;
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        if (thresholdBinaryImage <= data[i][j]) {
            binaryImageArray[i][j] = 255;
        } else {
            binaryImageArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
fwrite(header, sizeof(char), headerSize, binaryImageFilePointerOut);
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    fwrite(binaryImageArray[i], sizeof(char), height,
           binaryImageFilePointerOut);
}
fclose(binaryImageFilePointerOut);
fclose(imageFilePointerIn);
```

I have no idea why colors could be displayed at all?
For displaying I transfer the .img file into a .ras file with a code snipped from the internet. But I don't think that the error could be there since I saw others using the same code for transforming .img Grayscales into .ras just for displaying without having colors.

Would be nice to get any suggestion :).

Comment: In your code there is no any information about image format processing. It's only raw pixel processing without image file header. What tools do you use to open such raw files?

Comment: Yes as I said. I strip the 512 byte header from the .img file and add it after the pixel processing back to the new created .img file before the new pixels. After that I use another program to transfer the .img into an .ras file and then view it with XnView. But there should be nothing wrong with this other program, because others don't get the problems I have with grayscale images.

Comment: I could pinch down the problem more precise to the transferring function img2ras.exe. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820611/grayscale-image-conversion-img-to-ras-in-linux-grayscale-in-windows-white-an